# Find the radius of convergence of the Maclaurin series $x\cdot ln\left(x^2+\sqrt{x^4+9}\right)$

Tags: taylor-expansion

First you need to expand the function in a Maclaurin series. Then find the radius of convergence of the Maclaurin series.

My question: 
$$x\cdot ln\left(x^2+\sqrt{x^4+9}\right)$$

My solution:

$g(x)=ln\left(x^2+\sqrt{x^4+9}\right)$

$g'(x)=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^4+9}}=2x\cdot (x^{4}+9)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$

Everything, I decided to see my solution below.

Comment: $$(x^4+9)^{\dfrac12}=9^{\dfrac12}\left(1+\dfrac{x^4}9\right)^{\dfrac12}$$ See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series#Convergence

Comment: I do not see the formula.

Comment: What  would you if Wolfram Alpha did not exist ?

Comment: But he's there :)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Help me please. Although this would expand the binomial.

Comment: Another way to go is to note that you have (almost) the $\text{arsinh}$ function, whose Maclaurin series can be obtained once the series for the $\arcsin$ function is known, and maybe it is to you?

Comment: @mickep look down, I had already decided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$g(x)=ln\left(x^2+\sqrt{x^4+9}\right)$$

$$g'(x)=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^4+9}}$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{4}+9}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{9}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{x^4}{9}+1}}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot(\frac{x^4}{9}+1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\left(1+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\frac{1-\frac{1}{2}\cdot \left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)\cdot ...\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}-n\right)\cdot \frac{x^{4n}}{4^n}}{n!}\right)\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}\cdot \left(1+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\left(-1\right)^n\cdot \left(\frac{\left(2n-1\right)!!}{2^n\cdot n!}\right)\cdot \frac{x^{4n}}{4^n}\right)\right) at |x|<\sqrt{2}$$
$$g'(x)=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^{4}+9}}=2x\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot \left(1+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\left(-1\right)^n\cdot \left(\frac{\left(2n-1\right)!!}{2^n\cdot n!}\right)\cdot \frac{x^{4n}}{4^n}\right)\right)=$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}\cdot \left(1+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\left(-1\right)^n\cdot \left(\frac{\left(2n-1\right)!!}{2^n\cdot n!}\right)\cdot \frac{x^{4n+1}}{4^n}\right)\right)at |x|<\sqrt{2}$$

Integrating, we obtain:
$$g(x)=\frac{2}{3}\cdot \left(x+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\left(-1\right)^n\cdot \left(\frac{\left(2n-1\right)!!}{2^n\cdot n!\cdot \left(4n+2\right)}\right)\cdot \frac{x^{4n+2}}{4^n}\right)\right)+C$$

Since $g(0)=ln(3)$, then $C=ln(3)$

We obtain the final result: 
$$f(x)=x\cdot g(x)=\frac{2}{3}\cdot \left(x^2+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\left(-1\right)^n\cdot \left(\frac{\left(2n-1\right)!!}{2^n\cdot n!\cdot \left(4n+2\right)}\right)\cdot \frac{x^{4n+3}}{4^n}\right)\right)+x\cdot ln\left(3\right)$$